# Calling console command within command and get the output in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a few console command in Symfony2 and I need to execute one command from another command with some parameters.

After successfull execution of the second command **I need to get the result (as an array for example)**, not the display output.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Here](http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/06/calling-commands-within-commands-in-symfony2/) you can have a basic command inside a command. The output from the second command can be a json, then you just have to decode the output json to retrieve your array.

```
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:fixtures:load');
$arguments = array(
    //'--force' => true
    ''
);
$input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

if($returnCode != 0) {
    $text .= 'fixtures successfully loaded ...';
    $output = json_decode(rtrim($output));
}
```

Comment: What If I use in depended command `OutputInterface` with the method `writeln`, so I have a some string and I cannot to decode this.

Comment: `writeLn` just add a newline, I think you just need to `trim` or [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) the result.

Comment: I do not want parse the result, I am looking another way. Perhaps, I did not understand you.

Comment: You trim the output inside the first command, not inside the second one. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `var_dump($output)` from the first command says that is an instance of `Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput`. Actually, I expected such result and could not understand you.

Comment: just a note. Make sure that a command you call have all required arguments because if you dont there wont be any exception or output displayed.

Comment: FYI: It is absolutely necessary to have `''` at the end of your `$arguments` array for this to work! Otherwise you'll receive `RuntimeException: Not enough arguments.`!

Answer (score 22):

you have to pass the command in the arguments array, and to avoid the confirmation dialog in doctrine:fixtures:load you have to pass --append and not --force

```
    $arguments = array(
    'command' => 'doctrine:fixtures:load',
    //'--append' => true
    ''
);
```

or it will fail with error message “Not enough arguments.”

Answer (score 12):

There is an new Output class (as of [v2.4.0](https://github.com/symfony/Console/tree/v2.4.0/Output)) called `BufferedOutput`.

This is a very simple class that will return and clear the buffered output when the method `fetch` is called:

```
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $code = $command->run($input, $output);

    if($code == 0) {
        $outputText = $output->fetch();
        echo $outputText;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I did the following

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;

$tmpFile = tmpfile();
$output  = new StreamOutput($tmpFile);
$input   = new ArrayInput(array(
    'parameter' => 'value',
));

$command = . . .
$command->run($input, $output);

fseek($tmpFile, 0);
$output = fread($tmpFile, 1024);
fclose($tmpFile);

echo $output;
```

¡it works!

Answer (score 1):

As an update for [Onema's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808687/12894421), in Symfony 3.4.x (used by Drupal 8),

1. you also need to set `setAutoExit(false)`,
2. and the command returns an `int(0)` if successful.

Here's the updated example that I'm using to script [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) commands in php for a Drupal 8.8 project. This gets a list of all composer packages as json, then decodes that into a php object.

```php
<?php 

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Composer\Console\Application;

$input = new ArrayInput([
  'command' => 'show', 
  '--format'=>'json',
]);

$output = new BufferedOutput();
$application = new Application();

// required to use BufferedOutput()
$application->setAutoExit(false);
// composer package list, formatted as json, will be barfed into $output 
$status = $application->run($input, $output);
if($status === 0) {
  // grab the output from the $output buffer
  $json = $output->fetch();
  // decode the json string into an object
  $list = json_decode($json);
  // Profit!
  print_r($list);
}

?>
```

The output will be something like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [installed] => Array
        (
            ... omitted ...

            [91] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => drupal/core
                    [version] => 8.9.12
                    [description] => Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.
                )
            ... omitted ...
        )

)
```

With the help of [Onema's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808687/12894421) Google found the rest of the solution for me [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/command_in_controller.html).

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's old post and above answers solves the problem with a bit of digging. In Symfony2.7, I had a bit issue making it work, so with above suggestions, I dug a little and have compiled the full answer here. Hope it will be useful for someone.

[Using Console command under console command](http://php-webdeveloper.com/?p=88)